# Can Bash store the command in history at the *start* of execution?

Tags: bash

My Bash saves commands to the history file once the command has finished running, using `PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r;"`. Is there a way (without patching Bash itself, modifying my commands, or any I/O side effects like `echo`ing the command before running it) to save the command when it *starts* running rather than when it finishes?

Answer (score 1):

```
trap 'history -a; history -c; history -r' DEBUG
```

will [run that specified command](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-trap):

> before every simple command, `for` command, `case` command, `select` command, every arithmetic `for` command, and before the first command executes in a shell function

It does mean *every*. The typed command is already in the in-memory history and will be written to disk.